# Makefile: run bash script via 'make all' command BEFORE global variables initialization

Tags: c++, bash, makefile

Is it possible to execute bash script through command 'make all' **before** variable initialization. The idea is that this script compiles idls and creates new directories in whitch puts .h and .cpp files etc.. and the variables in the makefile have to be initialized after this script is executed.

BR,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a good design, but here's one way to do it:

```
all:
    bash-script
    $(MAKE) other-things

other-things: some-prereq $(FOO)
    other-stuff $(BAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning that `make` supports lazy evaluation, meaning it doesn't expand variables until they are actually used in a command (or if you use `:=` instead of `=` when you assign values). This allows you to modify variables right until the last moment (when they are used in a command line).

Quoting from [this Makefile doc](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/makefile.html#makefile.variables):

```
A variable is evaluated when it is part of the right side of the ``:='' or the ``!=''
operator, or directly before executing a shell command which the variable is part of.
In all other cases, make(1) performs lazy evaluation, that is, variables are not
evaluated until there's no other way. The ``modifiers'' mentioned in the man page
also evaluate the variable.
```